# Move console logs to kibana in angular 2

Tags: angular, kibana

I have a requirement in angular 2 like, i want move all console logs to a server like Logstash and want to view those logs in Kibana.  Created my own logging service as follows.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LoggerService {
    enabled = true;
    noop = () => {};

    constructor() {
                // You can do a check on your environment or some other flag to 
                // enable/disable logging
        // if ((<any>'<%= ENV %>') === 'prod') this.enabled = false;
    }

    get debug() {
        if (this.enabled) return console.debug.bind(console);
        return this.noop;
    }

    get error() {
        if (this.enabled) return console.error.bind(console);
        return this.noop;
    }

    get log() {
        if (this.enabled) return console.log.bind(console);
        return this.noop;
    }

    get info() {
        if (this.enabled) return console.info.bind(console);
        return this.noop;
    }

    get warn() {
        if (this.enabled) return console.warn.bind(console);
        return this.noop;
    }

}
```

so i can use the service in some other components like as follows.

constructor(private loggerService LoggerService){

```
 this.loggerService.log("some error");
```

}

But the above line prints logs in console. i want move those logs to server, so that we can see when ever we want. I google a lot for this requirement, but didn't get any stuff in angular2. But found a blog where it implemented in angular 1.x.

https://blog.donkeycode.com/superpower-angular-logging-with-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-part-1-cfb612da4b87

Could some one please help me here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any help here? I've similar requirement to use ELK stack with angular.